# I've had my driving license for just a few weeks, but need to rent a car early march in Los Angeles. Is it possible?

Tags: car-rentals, rental, los-angeles

Also is it possible to use a credit card that's not in my name?

Comment: How old are you ?

Comment: @Hilmar I'm 23 years old.

Comment: @jcaron The credit card is not in my name, as I can't get a credit card in time. I'm 23 years old.

Answer (score 3):

It will be tough, as most larger car rental agencies want you to be 25 or older and have x years of license; some allow below, but charge you through the nose for that. 
I cannot name specific companies that allow it, but probably the farther you go from big to obscure, the easier it gets. You will be able to find that info on the internet, together with prices.

You cannot use someone else's credit card. If the credit card holder is there (in person), *he/she* can rent the car, and add you as an additional driver (and he/she can then walk away and you drive all the time and return the car on your own)

Edit: if you go to some little hole-in-the-wall-rental, they *might* take someone else's credit card, but think twice before you drive a car from that level of shop.

Comment: Straight to the point. I have one thing to add: phone up the company. I managed to rent a car at aselectrentacar.com in Anaheim for a somewhat reasonably price. 22 years old, had my license for 4 months, but they didn't mind.